# Django m2m how to use name instead of name_id

Tags: django, python-3.x, bootstrap-tags-input

i want to add tags for new posts. I use bootstrap tags input. 
It works only if I write tags_id, not tag title. And if I write new numbers, it saves post with new number tag.

How to change tag_id to tag_title in m2m db table or other way to fix it?

**models**

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True)

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, blank=True, unique=True)
    body = RichTextField()
    date_pub = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Tag, blank=True, related_name='posts')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    views = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
```

**views**

```
def post(self, request):
    tags = request.POST.getlist('tags')
    for tag in tags:
        objs, created = Tag.objects.get_or_create(title=tag, slug=tag)
    bound_form = self.model_form(request.POST))
    if bound_form.is_valid():
        post = bound_form.save(commit=False)
        post.author = request.user
        post.save()
        post.tags.add(objs)
        post.save()

        new_obj = bound_form.save()
        return redirect(new_obj)
    return render(request, self.template, context={'form': bound_form})
```

**form**

```
class PostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = ['title', 'slug', 'body', 'tags']
        widgets = {
            'title': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'slug': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'body': forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
            'tags': forms.SelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'data-role': 'tagsinput'}),

        }
        exclude = ['author',]
```

I want to have tags as words not id's. Now when I add words is display error:
"qwe" is not a valid value. 
It wants numbers and maybe to fix displaying all tags in select.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5sHg.jpg)

Comment: Your question is a bit confusing, can you clarify what you mean by "tag_id" and "tag_title"?

Comment: There is relation between post and tag in post_tags. it is created bu many to many
id post_id tag_id

Comment: Since title isn't defined as unique, you can't use title directly. You have to define your own form field that takes a list of tags as input and process that list yourself fetching the corresponding tags and adding them to your m2m relationships. Also you'll probably want to decide what to do with uppercase/lowercase, similar tags (one word/two words), when to create new tags etc... For the display, override the `__str__()` method on your `Tag` model or override the form field and its `label_from_instance()`method.

Comment: tag slug is unique. and title=slug. or title should be unique too

Comment: So the user can only choose from existing tags? Or can he add new ones? That makes a big difference here.

Comment: write new tags. bootstrap tags intup adds new tags in selectMultiple and create such tag in db. it renders like this <option value="tag">tag</option> but form wants tags_id in value <optionvalue="title_id">tag</option>

Answer (score 2):

The way your model is defined, you can't use `title` as a unique identifier for your tag. Also if you let people create new tags, you probably want to take into account that "windsurfing", "Windsurfing" and "wIndsurfing" are all the same thing.

Also since you want users to be able to add new tags, you can't use tag ids in your form, since new tags don't have an id yet (this would only work if you were letting users pick from existing tags).

So your HTML form needs to post a list of strings to the Django form. And in your form you need to process these strings to save as tags:

- In your `PostForm`, add a field `tags` as a `TextInput` field. That's the one you'll display as bootstrap tags input in your HTML form.
- Remove `'tags'` from the list of `fields` in your ModelForm.
- Override the `__init__()` method of `PostForm` to set the initial values of `tags` to be the comma-separated list of titles: `self.fields['tags'].initial = ",".join([tag.title for tag in self.instance.tags.all()])`
- Override the `clean_tags()` method to make sure the input is a comma-separated list of strings, maybe changing them all to lower-case.
- Override the `save()` method to process the tags:

```
def save(commit=True):
    post = super().save(commit=commit)
    if commit:  # only save new tags if commit == True
        tags_titles = self.cleaned_data['tags'].split(",")
        for title in tags_titles:
            tag = Tag.objects.get_or_create(title=title.lower())  # assuming slug is auto-created when saving and all titles are saved lowercase
            post.tags.add(tag)
    return post
```

So basically your forms just handle a string (comma-separated list of strings) which are the titles of your tags. And your Django form translates that back to the actual `Tag` objects.

Comment: did work for me with:
1. `self.initial['tags'] = ",".join([tag.title for tag in self.instance.tags.all()])`
2. not removing from fields
3. `widgets = {
            'tags': TextInput(attrs={'size': '100'}),
       }`